# Activate non default site with NetMsmqActivator

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq, netmsmqbinding

Is it possible to have the NetMsmqActivator service activate a site that is running on another port than 80?

As far as I know you can't specify a port number on a net.msmq URI so I can't think of any way that the NetMsmqActivator would be able to find the correct site if it runs on any other port than a default one (80). 
Can someone confirm this?